# Кеширование данных в SQL CLR функции

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr

Допустим, есть `CLR` функция, которая имеет статический словарь, где сохраняется некоторый кеш.

Наблюдая с кешем, я заметил, что он живет не в рамках выполнения запроса, а вообще глобально => другие запросы из других сессий могут с ним работать.

На мой взгляд, актуализировать такой кеш очень тяжело и опасно, так как весь сервер может с ним работать=> нельзя найти подходящий момент для его актуализации.

Так же при обновлении кеша возможно, что часть запроса выполнится с одними данными, а другая с другими, что не верно.

Можно ли добиться того, что бы каждый запрос имел собственных кеш?

**Коротко о моей функции**

Моя функция принимает на вход некоторый веб ресурс и парсит его путь.
Затем, получает название сервера и его IP и позже добавляет эти данные в кеш, который представлен в виде словаря с конкуренцией.
При повторной встречи этого же ресурса, он берется из кеша, а вычисляется. Если ресурса не существует, то выводятся спец. данные.

А теперь представим ситуацию:

Выполняется запрос и кеширует данные-все хорошо.

Затем какой-то ресурс перестает существовать.

Запускаем новый запрос и ресурс берется из кеша, как валидный, что неправильно.

Хотелось бы иметь актуальность кеша в момент запуска и изолированный от других запросов.

Comment: Что в вашей системе "запрос"? У вас web и это HTTP-запрос от клиента?

Comment: @PashaPash,Sql-запрос, который использует CLR функцию.

Comment: Так может не делать словарь статическим?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, так нельзя. Так как MS SQL может извлекать только статические функции.

Comment: А вариант использовать для кэша временную таблицу не подходит? из CLR-функций можно делать контекстно-зависимые вызовы в БД. Завернуть запрос в транзакцию и работать с контекстом транзакции... Сам не пробовал, не было необходимости пока

Comment: @rdorn, могу ошибаться, но у функции нет контекста.https://stackoverflow.com/a/493023/4244707 => нужно переделывать функцию в процедуру. А как временную таблицу создавать? Получается, что вызывающий код должен создать таблицу и передать ее название в функцию?

Comment: перечитал вопрос еще раз. Меня смущает, что с одной стороны вы говорите, про кеширование адреса, с другой - если ресурс не валиден, то в кэше его не должно быть. Т.к. ресурс может помереть в любой момент, даже во время записи его в кэш, то необходимость в самом кэше кажется весьма сомнительной. Да у sql-функции контекста нет. про временные таблицы читать тут https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @rdorn, по идее, не зная контекста, я не могу создать временную таблицу и работать с ней. Получается, что придется передавать в функцию то, в какой базе выполняется запрос и т п вещи. Касательно примера, который я привел: он упрощенный и свиду может показаться, что кеш-ненужен, но это не так. В любом случае вопросы заключается:"Как сделать так, что бы кеш был не глобальным, а в пределах выполнения запроса.", что бы пока жил(выполнялся) запрос и жил кеш.

Comment: тогда только один вариант, разделить функции вычисления адреса и выполнения запроса. В начале запроса в отдельную переменную сохранять результат вычисления и передавать этот результат в функцию обращения к ресурсу столько раз, сколько потребуется. Переменные запроса живут только в запросе.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю если очень хочется, то придется этот функционал написать самостоятельно.
Идея в том, что запросы в одной сессии SQL не могут выполняться параллельно:

1. Во время выполнения передавать в функцию CLR `@@SPID` и хранить
   кэши для каждого `@@SPID`
2. После и/или перед выполнением запроса очищать кэш для данного
   `@@SPID` (или отдельной функцией или спец. параметром)

P.S. Я не думаю, что идея кэша в CLR правильная. Можно, например, предварительно группировать данные в T-SQL по ресурсам или названиям серверов и уже потом проводить вычисления в CLR. Тогда не будет повторяющихся данных и кэш не нужен.